# fews trigger, reset forms

Tags: php, jquery

I have two form which works after form submit on change. I want add button which will reset value in form to deafult. I added below juqery but works only first value.

```
<form action="xxxx.php" method="post">
   <select name="first" onchange="this.form.submit()">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option> 
</form>
<form action="xxxx.php" method="post">
   <select name="two" onchange="this.form.submit()">
     <option>A</option>
     <option>B</option>
     <option>C</option>
</form>
<a href="#" id="clean" class="btn btn-transparent"><span>Clean</span><
```

```
$("#clean").click(function () {
    $('select[name="first"]').val("1").trigger('change');
    $('select[name="two"]').val("A").trigger('change'); 
});
```

Comment: would an input `type='reset'` not work for your needs? You have not shown both forms nor the buttons.....

Comment: I corrected post. I should write option in select?

Comment: Is the button to reset ( to default values ) elements in **both** forms or is there to be a button for each form that resets just that form?

Comment: I want have only one button to reset value in two forms.

Comment: `<input type='reset' value='Clean'/>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* Create a delegated event listener that process the `button` click events. */
document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  /* 
  if the currently clicked element is the button then query the dom 
  for all forms and reset the elements within by calling the `reset` method
  on the form
  */
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLSpanElement && e.target.parentNode instanceof HTMLAnchorElement ){
    // an anchor element is not a button - prevent the default behaviour!
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // find the forms, iterate through and call `reset()` on each form.
    document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(form=>form.reset())
  }
});
```

```html
<!--
  added options to the select and a new input to each form so that the effect of the
  `button` click can be observed.
-->
<form action="xxxx1.php" method="post">
   <select name="status_date" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option>1
    <option>2
    <option>3
    <option>5
    <option>6
    <option>8
   </select>
   <input type='text' name='sport' />
</form>

<form action="xxxx2.php" method="post">
   <select name="status_employees" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option>A
    <option>B
    <option>C
    <option>F
    <option>P
    <option>T
   </select>
   <input type='text' name='fruit' />
</form>
<a href="#" id="clean" class="btn btn-transparent"><span>Clean</span></a>
```

Comment: Your solution is great but I need solution which not reset forms but add new value as I showed in my post. I need trigger which set in form values then submit forms after click clean.

Comment: The question explicitly mentions `reset` - `I want add button which will reset value in form to deafult` .... confused.com

Comment: I right, my mistake, I wrote wrong description of my post. Do you have any ideas how add trigger or another solution to set values in two forms?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `add trigger` or `set values in two forms`. Using the above code it would be easy to adapt that to add new elements into each form or do other things but it's not clear what you mean

Comment: In short. I use forms to filter data from databases and it works. After select option from each form I assign this value to session that after refresh page will lest it disappear.

When I had one form I don't have problem becuase I seted trigger which added value which I want after click clean but now triggers  don't work when I have two forms.